# List and count the most weight path from the root to the leafs of a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I have to return the number of nodes and the weight of the most weight path from the root to some leaf. Note that the tree is not a Binary Search Tree, is unsorted.

i.e.:

```
     6
   /   \
  9     6
 /     / \
3     1   19
```

Then, I have to return the integer `6 + 6 + 19 = 31` and print the node `6 - 6 - 19`

So, this is my code:

```
int heavierPath ( Node * tree ) {
    if ( ! tree ) return 0;

    int leftWeight = heavierPath( tree->left );
    int rightWeight= heavierPath( tree->right );

    if ( leftWeight >= rightWeight ) {
        if ( tree->left )
            cout << tree->left->value << endl;
        return tree->value + leftWeight;
    }
    else {
        cout << tree->right->value << endl;

        return tree->value + rightWeight;
    }
};
```

And the result is `31`, but I see all the nodes values in the terminal.

How can I do to fix it and print only the elements that lies in the heavier path? (only recursive)

Thanks!

Comment: Did my suggestion work? I have tested it and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work after I edited it.

Take a look at: http://ideone.com/OGcyun as an example.

**Your problem:**

Consider the graph as:

```
     6
   /   \
  9     6
 /     / \
3     1   19
```

Number each node so:

```
     0
   /   \
  1     2
 /     / \
3     4   5
```

Consider the case where you are at node 1.
You ask for the better path which gives you `leftWeight = 3` and `rightweight = 0` and you print the "better" path, 3. which isn't part of the end result.

**The solution**

To solve this problem, I passed up additional data up in a `retstruct` which contain the `path` (the heaviest path up to this point), `value` (to make printing easier), `sum` (to determine the better path).

Then I changed the function to:

```
retstruct* heavierPath ( Node * tree ) {
    if ( ! tree ) return new retstruct();

    //Get both paths
    retstruct* leftWeight = heavierPath( tree->left );
    retstruct* rightWeight= heavierPath( tree->right );

    //Find the "heavier" path
    if ( leftWeight->sum >= rightWeight->sum ) {
        //Delete lighter path
        delete_retstruct(rightWeight);
        //Pass up the better path with the correct data
        return new retstruct(leftWeight, tree->value, tree->value + leftWeight->sum);
    } else {
        //Delete lighter path
        delete_retstruct(leftWeight);
        //Pass up the better path with the correct data
        return new retstruct(rightWeight, tree->value, tree->value + rightWeight->sum);
    }
};
```

Added the delete_retstruct function:

```
void delete_retstruct (retstruct* path) {
    if (path->path == NULL) {
        delete path;
    } else {
        delete_retstruct(path->path);
    }
}
```

and the printPath function:

```
void printPath (retstruct* path) {
    if (path->path != NULL) {
        std::cout << " - " << path->value;
        printPath(path->path);
    }
}
```

This is used like so:

```
retstruct* path = heavierPath(tree);

//Print sum
std::cout << "Sum: " << path->sum << std::endl;

//Print path
std::cout << "Path: " << path->value;
printPath(path->path);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Sum: 31
Path: 6 - 6 - 19
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to make two functions,first function will find the leaf where path from root to it is maximum. So assuming you have pointer to such leaf here is the function to print the path.

```
bool print(struct node *r, struct node *leaf)
{

    if (r == NULL)
        return false;
    //will print if it is leaf or on path to leaf
    if (r == leaf || print(r->left, leaf) || print(r->right, leaf) )
    {
        printf("%d ", r->val); // this will print in reverse order
                               // if you want to print from root, store values in stack and then print the value after the function call
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This function will print all the nodes!

Comment: Nope only on path from root to heaviest node. Because if part will be true only if it lies on that path. Did you try to implement it?

Comment: It won't I checked. Observe the function carefully. Think when the if inside the function will be true? Only when the path reaches the required leaf node.

Comment: I am sorry you are correct. The hard part is actually finding the node though. Once you have the required node you can simply traverse the parent nodes until you get to the top.

Comment: That's what I have done, though op is able to find required leaf node so I just helped with print

Comment: U would have to use back pointers for the purpose which author doesn't use. So ur approach can't be used

Comment: The problem is that you are traversing the tree downwards. You basically use a depth first search to find the path. This is really inefficient as you can imagine. A solution is to have printPath take the found node as a first parameter and the base node as second. In the if condition you can replace the prints which take the child nodes as parameters with a printh taking the parent of the current node as a parameter.

Comment: In his attempted solution there wasn't a need to use parent pointers, that doesn't mean that the nodes don't have them though. Why would anyone even implement nodes without parent pointers anyway? In any case I am just pointing out that a depth search traversal algorithm could be avoided.

Comment: I rarely see any one using parent pointers in binary tree? Do you?

Comment: I do but that may be because I work a lot with self balanced trees. After a quick search it seems that parent pointers are not used in normal binary trees as much unless they make operations easier. There are certainly ways a depth first search can be avoided when it comes to the op's needs though but I now understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing printing the node with finding the sum. The later has to visit all child-nodes while printing only has to visit the ones in the path.
Below is a possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Node
{
    Node(int value = 0, Node* left = nullptr, Node* right = nullptr) :
        value{value},
        left{left},
        right{right}
    {}

    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

std::unordered_map<Node*, int> map;

int pathSum(Node* node)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (map.find(node) == map.end())
    {
        return (pathSum(node->left) > pathSum(node->right)) 
                ? (map[node] = node->value + pathSum(node->left)) 
                : (map[node] = node->value + pathSum(node->right));
    }
    else
    {
        return map[node];
    }
}

void printPath(Node* node)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    std::cout << node->value << std::endl;
    if (pathSum(node->left) > pathSum(node->right))
    {
        printPath(node->left);
    }
    else
    {
        printPath(node->right);
    }
}

int main() {

    Node* tree = new Node(6, 
                             new Node(9,
                                         new Node(3)),
                             new Node(6,
                                         new Node(1),
                                         new Node(19)));

    std::cout << "Biggest Sum: " << pathSum(tree) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Biggest Sum Path: " << std::endl;
    printPath(tree);

    return 0;

}
```

In recursive solutions such as this, it's a good idea to cache the results hence the std::unordered_map. The code has been tested at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fCQVMr).